# How to enable SSL security to Camel Rest DSL endpoints

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I'm new to security world and I want my Camel REST DSL API should have some authentication layer (may be SSL) before hitting the Rest endpoints.

I've gone through the different documentations of Camel security measurements but it didn't cleared the best way to use and how to use.

Could someone provide me an example of REST DSL with SSL authentication layer.

Comment: It depends on which underlying component you use to handle the actual HTTPS transport (jetty, netty, servlet...). For, say, the servlet component, that configuration lies outside of Camel - you'd need to check how to configure your servlet container or JEE server of choice. For something like the jetty component, which creates its own web server, you'd need to check the docs for the specific component (but you should be able to set the appropriate options with `componentProperty`/`endpointProperty` in the [builder-style config](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html#RestDSL-ConfiguringRestDSL).

Comment: Thnaks @Cyäegha..here we have already built the service using Netty4-HTTP component, can you help me in how to add security for this component.